# Autogluon.core space attribute not found

Tags: hyperparameters, autogluon

I am trying to set hyperparameter for autogluon model as:

```
import autogluon.core as ag


    nn_options = {
        'num_epochs': 10,  
        'learning_rate': ag.space.Real(1e-4, 1e-2, default=5e-4, log=True),  
        'activation': ag.space.Categorical('relu', 'softrelu', 'tanh'),  
        'dropout_prob': ag.space.Real(0.0, 0.5, default=0.1),  
    }
    
    gbm_options = { 
        'num_boost_round': 100,  
        'num_leaves': ag.space.Int(lower=26, upper=66, default=36),  
    }
```

But I am getting **AttributeError autogluon.core has no attribute space.**

Answer (score 1):

`autogluon.core.space` was moved to `autogluon.common.space`.

See [release notes](https://auto.gluon.ai/stable/whats_new/v1.0.0.html) and [autogluon.common.space](https://auto.gluon.ai/1.0.0/api/autogluon.common.space.html) documentation.